# How to optimize two css classes into one

Tags: css, reactjs, optimization, build, frontend

I have a project made with react and I want to optimize the css.

I have this code:

```css
.class-1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.class-2 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Is there a possible way to optimize like this during the build?

```css
.class-3 {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: `margin:15px 0;` is even shorter :) But, do you need both classes to remain like this ? if yes, both classes can be attached to a single element in your HTML instead making a third one .How ever, if you look at bootstrap classes , you have one for each possible direction and horizontal, vertical and 4directions :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, if you need a `margin-top` but no `margin-bottom`  or the other way around you can't do that, however if you always use both classes you can use an even shorter version `margin: 15px 0;`

Comment: Yeah, but I mean if there is a way to optimize the CSS combining the .class-1 and .class-2 and the output be like .class-3

.class-1 and .class-2 will be purged, because .class-3 does the same as .class-1 and class-2.

And in this way I only use one class for the element in the HTML so the web gains more speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both classes to your HTML element or combine the margins into one class like this:

```css
.class1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.class2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.class3 {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='class1 class2'>My element with 2 classes</div>

<div class='class3'>My element with 1 class</div>
```

It all depends if you want to keep the classes separate for other areas of your code, or if you will never need those margins in separate classes.